# First non blank cell in row as an array for the column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

First non blank cell in a row as an array formula for the whole column.

None of these seem to work.

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(transpose(V2:Y),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not null limit 1",0))

=ArrayFormula(index(V2:Y,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(V2:Y),0)))

=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("*", V2:Y, 1,FALSE))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S3svXvdC45VqCFu1710_VrEuo4kWo0kKe6CuxbpnqnI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:D),,99^99))), " "),,1))
```

[image: 0]