# Using Array Formula, return any non blank cell in row

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Nearly found the answer here: [First non blank cell in row as an array for the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719780/first-non-blank-cell-in-row-as-an-array-for-the-column) But this formula only returns the **first word** of each cell.

Here's my [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hX2f_M0ONwyc9pqPkwy0d0P4kaMt1txJbOgGhw3azIQ/edit#gid=0)

**COLUMN M** is the copied formula from the above stackoverflow answer.

The only way I can get the result I need is by duplicating the formula using '&', adding a space (" ") and TRIM() at the beginning as it adds additional spaces.

Is there any way of simplifying my formula in **COLUMN N**?

Answer (score 1):

I added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in M1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header of Choice";IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:L)," ",COLUMNS(B2:L)))))})`

As I see it, this is about as concise, flexible and powerful as the formula can get. It takes advantage of a quirk in how `QUERY` headers are handled.

This formula can handle any number of words in a cell. Of note, it assumes (as shown in your sheet) that there will only be *one* string to return per row in B:L. If there will be more than one possible return per row, the formula can be easily modified to include a delineator.

Answer (score 0):

shorter:

```
={"SHORT FX"; INDEX(IF(A1:A="",,TRIM(
IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:L),,9^9))), " "),,1))&" "&
IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:L),,9^9))), " "),,2))&" "&
IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:L),,9^9))), " "),,3))
)))}
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
={"SHORTEST"; INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:L),,9^9)))))}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this shortens the first part but doesn't shorten the 2nd:

IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:L),,9^9))), " "),,1))&" "&
IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:L),,9^9))), " "),,2))&" "&
IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:L),,9^9))), " "),,3))